# Replace all files in Folder with 1 file but keeping their original names in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, replace, gulp

I have a folder that has bunch of images, i want gulp to replace each one of them with the new image file but without changing their original name

```
gulp.task('img', function() {
    return gulp.src(`source/template/img/**/*`, base: './')
    .pipe()// A pipe to replace multipe files with one file but keeping their original name
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`./`));
});
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This makes use of `vinyl-map` to handle the pipe function. It also uses `readFileSync` as I couldn't get it to work async. If someone knows how to do so, please modify my answer or leave a comment/new answer.

`MightyRiversbank.jpg` is the template image that replaces all existing images in the `tempImages` directory.

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const fs = require('fs')
const map = require('vinyl-map')
const gutil = require('gulp-util')

gulp.task('replaceImages', function() {
    const replaceImage = map(function(code, filename, callback){
      const data = fs.readFileSync('MightyRiversbank.jpg')
      return data
    })

    gutil.log("replacing images")
    return gulp.src(`tempImages/**/*`)
    .pipe(replaceImage)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`tempImages`))
})
```